# Using Joins inside Create function - Postgres error

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.5

The normal query executes fine

```
SELECT   * 
FROM  tracks 
LEFT JOIN albums ON tracks.album_id = albums.id
WHERE albums.title like '%a%'
order by similarity(albums.title, 'al')
desc limit 20
```

when placed inside the function throws an error

> syntax error at or near "AS"

here is the function

```
CREATE FUNCTION search_new_tracks(search text) 
returns table AS $$ 

SELECT   * 
FROM  tracks 
LEFT JOIN albums ON tracks.album_id = albums.id
WHERE albums.title like '%a%'
order by similarity(albums.title, 'al')
desc limit 20

$$ language sql stable;
```

what shoud be the return type? I may be using the wrong return type.

Comment: You need to list the columns of both tables `returns table (id integer, name text, ...) as ...` whatever they are called. And don't use `select *` inside the function. But why a function? Wouldn't a view be more appropriate here?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the response, including the column names worked, views is a good idea but not using it here because it will lead to some major modifications, and what's the downside of using select * inside a function.

Comment: The `returns table (...)` needs to match the `select ...`  part. It's a lot harder to get that right, if you use `select *`.